# Choose data from mongoDB in browser and display results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, web-applications, geojson

I am new to NodeJS, MongoDB and express.
I am able to insert, delete and update data but I dont really know how to work with it.
I want to choose some data(e.g. from a dropdown form) and then pass that data to some functions and calculate results. How is it possible to show the results to the client in the webpage(e.g. in a table)?
For example: I have different JSON objects stored in my database and now I want to select one by the name. Then do some calculations with it and show the results to the client.
Also: Is it possible to tell the Database to only accept valid JSON data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get specified data from the database and it will work a lot better with mongoose. You can define schema in mongoose and you can focus more on the data instead of how your data look like. And you can do validation to accept the valid data.

Comment: And how can I display the data in the html file? Because document.getinnerHtml wont work server side, right?

Comment: No it won't work. You can get data by using like user.find() or user.findOne() and you can get the data. After that you can pass that data to your rendered view or HTML page.